# help to prove the logical expression ¬¬A→A in HPC proof system

Tags: logic, formal-proofs, hilbert-calculus

I'm trying to prove the expression ¬¬A→A. I can use 3 axioms:

- A1: a→(b→a)
- A2: (a→(b→c))→((a→b)→(a→c))
- A3: (¬b→¬a)→(a→b),

MP rule and deduction theorem.

What am I doing wrong?

⊢ ¬¬A → A

¬¬A ⊢A deduction th.

1.¬¬A

2.¬¬A→(¬A→¬¬A) [A1]

3.¬A→¬¬A [MP(1,2)]

4.(¬A→¬¬A)→(¬A→A) [A3]

5.¬A→A [MP(3,4)]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I don’t think I can use the deduction theorem inside the proof like him

Comment: The Deduction Theorem is indeed typically not an inference rule. But, if you just take off that last line from the prloof that Matt Daly referenced, you can say that that is a proof of $\neg \neg a \vdash a$. And *therefore*, by the Deduction Theorem, it follows that $\vdash \neg \neg a \to a$. Also, here are a few more proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962525/derive-p-to-neg-neg-p-in-a-structure-with-not-and-implies

Comment: Thank you for the help:)