# How to prove that ├ (¬¬φ⇒φ) and ├ (φ⇒¬¬φ) based on deduction and/or proof by contradiction?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, hilbert-calculus

EDIT: someone just showed my the typo in the lecture notes.
instead of:

```
{¬¬φ,φ}├ φ
{¬¬φ,φ}├ ¬φ
```

it should be:

```
{¬¬φ,¬φ}├ ¬¬φ
{¬¬φ,¬φ}├ ¬φ
```

than by the third form of proof by contradiction we get that:

```
{¬¬φ}├ φ
```

and by deduction:

```
├ (¬¬φ→φ)
```

ORIGINAL POST:
Given Hilbert system and:

Deduction:

```
K∪{ψ}├ φ iff K├ (ψ⇒φ)
```

Proof by contradiction:

```
For every φ,ψ – {ψ,¬ψ}├ φ
Inconsistent set proves every verse
If K∪{¬φ} is inconsistent then K ├ φ
```

How can it be proven that:

```
├ (¬¬φ⇒φ)
├ (φ⇒¬¬φ)
```

I am studying from a lecture note that claims the set {¬¬φ,φ} is inconsistent because:

```
{¬¬φ,φ}├ φ
{¬¬φ,φ}├ ¬φ
```

But I can’t prove {¬¬φ,φ}├ ¬φ and frankly don’t see why it should be true given that ¬¬φ is supposed to be equivalent to φ – that is what we are trying to prove after all, so why would two equivalent verses prove their negation?
I will be grateful for every proof of the above mentioned, but if it is possible to confirm or deny the proof from my lecture notes (not mine, actually. I should hope I wouldn’t need help understanding my own notes. In fact they were written by a teacher, but are known to contain some typos) I will be especially grateful.

I do not study in English so I may have created some bad or non-conventional
translations, for which I apologize.

EDIT: as per @GitGud's request, here is a screenshot of the notes (the text is in Hebrew but I think the math notation is clear even without the text):
[image: screenshot of the notes]

Comment: There must be a typo. Any chance you can take a screenshot of the statement?

Comment: What "Hilbert system" ? And thus no Natural Deduction tag.

Comment: In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069497/prove-lnot-c-implies-lnot-b-implies-b-implies-c-without-the-deductio) you can find some initial useful results up to *Contraposition*.

Comment: Now you can use [Mendelson's proofs](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31).

Comment: You're right ... $\{ \varphi, \neg \neg \varphi \}$ is not inconsistent. Anyway, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962525/derive-p-to-neg-neg-p-in-a-structure-with-not-and-implies/2962597#2962597

Comment: @GitGud I posted here a pretty accurate translation of what the notes say.

Comment: @Zack I meant that there must be a typo in the original notes. The screenshot was just to validate this.

Comment: @GitGud this is what I thought you meant. hence my response: my post contains an accurate translation of the notes. If there is a typo in the notes it should be reflected in my translation. But since you insist I will add a screenshot.

Comment: @Zack I wasn't insisting, I was clarifying what I meant and what my intentions were. I thought you could have misinterpreted as me saying that there was a typo in your transcription.